# Bitwise operations in binary format in python

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, python-3.6

My program has two vars named: `IP` and `MASK`. Those variables contain numbers in binary format, for instance: `IP = "11100001"` and `MASK = "11000000"`.

I'm performing an `AND` operation like this:
`result = IP & MASK`.
This should give: `11000000`, but instead returns `10573888`. 
How can I make `AND` operations and keep the number in decimal?

I've looked around stackoverflow.com but I haven't found any similar situation, the only thing I've came across is to do manually an "algorithm" that performs this operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IP = 0b11100001
MASK = 0b11000000
Result = bin(IP and MASK)
print(Result)
```

Returns `0b11000000`

Pre-fixing with `0b` is a common way do denote that a number is in binary format. Similarly `0x` often denotes a hexadecimal number.

Comment: I wanted exactly this. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're entering the numbers in decimal. The bit patterns aren't what you expect:

```
>>> bin(11100001)
'0b101010010101111101100001'
>>> bin(11000000)
'0b101001111101100011000000'
>>> bin(11000000 & 11100001)
'0b101000010101100001000000'
>>> bin(10573888)
'0b101000010101100001000000'
```

To work with binary numbers, use the `0b` prefix:

```
>>> bin(0b11000000 & 0b11100001)
'0b11000000'
```

Comment: Thanks, this explanation clarificated a lot of things.